# Unable to click on Google Hangouts button

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, google-hangouts

I am unable to click on the 'Answer call' button in Google hangouts webapp [hangouts.google.com]. I can see the element in the developer console. However, when I try to reference the element in python, it throws an NoSuchElementException error.

```
answer_call = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.button.phroHd.jcsSsc')
```

Just wondering if anyone has any ideas. Thank you.

Comment: use javascript executor or Action to do this. I have solved this in java by using these.

Comment: @noor I was unable to get it working with javascript executor.

Answer (score 0):

```
iframes = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')
browser.switch_to_frame(iframes[6])
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('button.phroHd.jcsSsc').click()
```